# Storing values from file into array and extract values based on certain number

Tags: c++

file.txt

```
0 00 19
0 200 699
0 7000 8499
0 85000 89999
0 900000 949999
0 9500000 9999999
1 00 09
1 100 399
1 4000 5499
1 55000 86979
1 869800 998999
1 9990000 9999999
2 00 19
2 200 349
2 35000 39999
2 495 699
2 7000 8399
2 84000 89999
2 900000 949999
2 9500000 9999999
3 00 02
3 030 033
3 0340 0369
3 03700 03999
3 04 19
3 200 699
3 7000 8499
3 85000 89999
3 900000 949999
3 9500000 9999999
```

Assuming I only want the block where the first value is `3`, how can I store only the following into three separate arrays:

```
3 00 02
3 030 033
3 0340 0369
3 03700 03999
3 04 19
3 200 699
3 7000 8499
3 85000 89999
3 900000 949999
3 9500000 9999999
```

I have so far:

```
while (finished != EOF){
    finished = fscanf(fp,"%d %s %s\n", &areaScanned, &pubLow, &pubHigh);
}
```

That works fine but it stores the entire list. How can I narrow it down? Basically what I need to do is check if a certain number falls between a value on row 1, between column 1 and column 2, then row 2, value between col1 and col2, then row3, value between col1 and col2 etc.

Comment: What do you mean three separate arrays? What should each contain?

Comment: I understood it as storing each column into an array of numbers. But now when he posted that `fscanf` call I'm confused why he's reading the other columns as `%s`

Comment: @LihO, Oh, that makes more sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you probably don't want to use `fscanf`. Second, you almost certainly don't want to use three separate arrays, if you can possibly help it. If at all possible, you want something like:

```
struct whatever { 
    int a, b, c;

    friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, whatever &w) { 
        return is >> w.a >> w.b >> w.c;
    }
};

std::vector<whatever> w;

std:copy_if(std::istream_iterator<whatever>(infile),
            std::istream_iterator<whatever>(),
            std::back_inserter(w),
            [](whatever const &w) { return w.a == 3; } );
```

Comment: +1 I think he wants the final container indexible by the first value of each line, which in his data file is sequential, but he was rather unclear about that. Honestly this is about as solid an answer as he's going to get given the nebulous nature of the question and its presentation.

Comment: +1 for having the object read its field values.

Comment: This code is much too complicated and way beyond the scope of what we are learning in class. I don't understand any of it.